# How to develop with php and MySQL on a mac

Tags: macos, mac, php, mysql

I have recently started using a Mac, moving over from Windows. On Windows I use XAMPP for php and MySQL. What should I use on a mac?

I know Macs have built in php and the apache server but I am not sure if I should follow some of those guides online on how to set that whole thing up or if I should just install XAMPP and use that.

What should I do?

Comment: Personally I use XAMPP on my Mac.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking here? Are you asking for our preference? Both will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is to just use XAMPP on Mac OS X. I've been using it for the last few months without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have two options: MAMP and MAMP PRO, or the embebed PHP engine inside Netbeans.

I think the first options is the best one for you, 'cause it also have MySLQ Server.

Answer (score 0):

MAMP and XAMPP are both good options. **[Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/)** is another one. It installs a small virtual server on your system. It may be a bit more challenging than XAMPP. It's like a virtual linux machine running locally. Another option is Virtualbox with a Debian or Ubuntu guest.